# Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object on mac

Tags: vba, outlook

The message below is shown when running VBA on mac... any idea on how to fix it?

Run-time error '429':

ActiveX component can't create object

Code:

```
Sub send_email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rg1 As Range
Dim wordDoc

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


Set rg1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C7")

' Create mail
On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "lk@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Trial Email"
        .display
        .HTMLBody = "Hi Team" & ConvertRangeToHTMLTable(rg1) & .HTMLBody
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add the information at which line you get the error. I guess it is the line `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. Or maybe `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)`. Maybe [this](https://www.macexcel.com/examples/mailpdf/outlookmailexamples/) is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

CreateObject is Windows specific, it won't work on Mac: Outlook on Mac does not expose the same COM API it exposes on Windows.